# I want to create a systemverilog tag

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I want to create a [systemverilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemverilog) tag. There is already a [system-verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system-verilog) tag. however according to the IEEE 1800 standard, SystemVerilog is to be written as one word, not two.

Comment: I believe you have the rep to create the tag, just go do it! You could then suggest the synonym, though the question count is so few you might have a hard time finding the users to vote for it.

Comment: Or you could just ask a mod to change the tag to the correct syntax; probably easier for everyone involved.  In fact, since the question is here, a mod will probably see it.

Comment: Can tags be made case-sensitive? Because otherwise this form seems a little inconvenient, even if correct. I see systemc is already one word, but it's way shorter..

Comment: I tried to create a new tag, but got this message "You are attempting to create the tag [systemverilog]; however the tag [system-verilog] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta". So here I am.

Comment: I've raised this issue on Meta Stack Exchange. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362616/946172